# Dynamics 365 OrganizationServiceContext Linq Query with multiple Joins

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am running into an issue running most of my queries. I can generate a link query with a join to only one related entity at a time.  But when I run a LINQ query with multiple joins as in the example below, I get the "Sequence contains no elements" error.

```
var query =
(
    from permission in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.idoe_permission>()
        join contact in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.Contact>()
            on permission.idoe_contact_idoe_permission.Id equals contact.Id
        join corporation in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.idoe_corporation>()
            on permission.idoe_idoe_corporation_idoe_permission.Id equals corporation.Id
        join role in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.idoe_role>()
            on permission.idoe_idoe_role_idoe_permission.Id equals role.Id
    where contact.idoe_ADB2CID == request.UserId
    select new { Corporation = corporation, Role = role }
).ToList();
```

I am only able to "join" one entity at a time. Other examples I have seen allow multiple joins, but I have not been able to get this to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A dummy question - are you sure that this "should" return a result? Maybe there is no record that matches this query? I would suggest to build a FetchXML query (using Advanced Find) and checking if it returns a value that you desire. Also you should use lookup names as in Aron's answer, it would be much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the relationship names rather than the lookup field names in the joins. Using the lookup field names instead might look something like this:

```
var query = (from permission in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.idoe_permission>()
         join contact in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.Contact>() on permission.idoe_contactid.Id equals contact.Id
         join corporation in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.idoe_corporation>() on permission.idoe_corporationid.Id equals corporation.Id
         join role in context.CreateQuery<ServiceModel.Types.idoe_role>() on permission.idoe_roleid.Id equals role.Id
         where contact.idoe_ADB2CID == request.UserId
         select new { Corporation = corporation, Role = role }).ToList() ;
```